# How to check time window compliance in pyspark/spark.sql?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, datetime, pyspark

I have the following sample data:

[input_availability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93TQO.png)

And I want to check that each day a provider_id was available (busy = false) from 08:00 to 16:30 excluding their lunch breaks and their known unavailability (busy = true) such that the spark.sql based upon this sample data would return:

[output_availability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLOxY.png)

How can I check time windows like this using spark.sql (preferably) or, if too complex for SQL, in pyspark? If the provider is available earlier than 08:00 start_time_local or later than 16:30 end_time_local that's still passing for flag = 0.

I know I probably have to get the min(start_time_local) to compare against 08:00 and max(start_time_local) against 16:30 but I'm not sure how to handle the exceptions and comparing time windows in this way.

Comment: Welcome! Can you [please read](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557) about the problems with images of text and then edit your question to add transcriptions of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).